# While loop in R -

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm a beginner about R. How can I do a loop using "while", in order to get a sum of all natural numbers until this sum gets 1,000,000. When this sum exceed 1,000,000 , it has to stop (break). How can I do that?

Comment: there are plenty of documentation and examples in the `?'while'` help page and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+while)

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic way of doing a `while` `break` loop:

```
j <-  0

while(TRUE){
  j <- j+1
if(j>1000000)
break
}
```

to sum consecutive whole numbers in this loop:

```
j <-  0
while(TRUE){
  j <- j + (j+1)
if(j>1000000)
break
}
```